# ExtJs HtmlEditor image upload?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, extjs, web, extjs4

I am using ExtJs4.2.1 as the frontend and asp.net mvc 4 as the backend. My customer has the following requirements:

They wanna copy bunch of stuff from a document(like .docx file etc.) directly into the extjs's htmleditor. So, there will inevitably be mixtures of rich texts and images inside the editor, which is a problem because the html editor of extjs can not upload picture directly. So, I wonder if there is an solution for this? I googled a lot, and some of the answers will involve to add a extra button for the editor and pop up an add File panel to let the customer insert image. I think it is little bit tricky. Could I filter out the picture in the editor and directly upload it without popping up another selection panel? Anyway, is there a more elegant way to do things like this?

```
Any help relating this topic will be really appreciated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not tried this you could use TinyMCE which has a plugin that claims to do this http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:paste

There is an ExtJS component for TinyMCE https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?198699-Ext.ux.form.TinyMCETextArea-a-text-area-with-integrated-TinyMCE-WYSIWYG-Editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
ExtJs HtmlEditor image upload 

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'Test panel',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [{
            xtype: 'htmleditor',
            itemId: 'txtBody',
            fieldLabel: 'Body',
            enableFormat: false,
            enableFont: false,
            enableFontSize: false,
            enableColors: false,
            allowBlank: false,
            listeners: {
                render: function(editor) {
                    editor.getToolbar().add({
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'fileIUpload',
                        handler: function() {
                            new Ext.Window({
                                title: 'Image Upload',
                                closable: true,
                                itemId: 'wndImageUpload',
                                height: 120,
                                width: 300,
                                items: [{
                                    xtype: 'form',
                                    itemId: 'frmFileUpload',
                                    fileUpload: true,
                                    items: [{
                                        xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
                                        fieldLabel: 'Select Image',
                                        name: 'Upload',
                                        itemId: 'imgFileUploadField',
                                        labelWidth: '90',
                                        margin: '20 0 0 0'
                                    },

                                    {
                                        xtype: 'button',
                                        text: 'Submit',
                                        scope: this,
                                        margin: '15 0 0 200',
                                        //handler: function (config) {
                                        //    var ns = config.ns;
                                        //    var form = ns.frmFileUpload.getForm();
                                        //    form.submit({
                                        //        url: 'Admin/UploadEmailTemplateImage',
                                        //        success: function (fp, result) {
                                        //            var imagePath = '/Upload/EmailTemplateImage/' + result.result.data);
                                        //            var imageHeight = result.result.imageHeight;
                                        //            var imageWidth = result.result.imageWidth;
                                        //            var html = '<img src="' + imagePath + '" Height= "' + imageHeight + '" Width= "' + imageWidth + '"/>';
                                        //            ns.txtBody.setValue(html);
                                        //            ns.wndImageUpload.hide();
                                        //        },
                                        //        failure: function (fp, result) {
                                        //            Ext.Msg.alert(t('Error'), result.result.message);
                                        //        }
                                        //    });
                                        //}
                                    },

                                    ]
                                }]
                            }).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        ]
    }).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the editor to `Ext.ux.form.TinyMCETextArea`.
While creating the component, initialize the `tinyMCEConfig` parameter of the editor with a config object having `paste_data_images: true`